# Determine the type of triangle constructed on the polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Determine the type of triangle constructed on the polynomials: 
2-t+5t² , 3t²+2t+1 ,

if the scalar product is defined
as follows:

(f,g) = a₀b₀ + 2a₁b₁ + 3a₂b₂

I just don't understand what 'triangle constructed on the polynomials' means

Comment: Neither do I.....

Comment: @nonuser That's what it says in the problem...

Comment: I think it is a generalisation of Pascal's triangle. This is generated by the powers of $1+t$ and one can do the same by taking powers of other polynomials. Is that what you have been studying?

Comment: @user1172706 My course did not cover the Pascal triangle. Is it possible to 'convert' these polynomials to vectors, for example?

Comment: You can 'consider' $2-t+5t^2$ to be a way of encoding the vector $(2, -1, 5)$. But I don't think anyone can help you without knowing exactly what the course you are studying is about.

Comment: @user1172706
 its just a linear algebra 2 in technical univ.

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation of the regular scalar product $(a,b)$ is the length of the projection of vector $a$ onto vector $b$, or vice-versa. If you draw the two vectors, and a line joining the tip of $a$ to a point on $b$ which is $(a,b)$ from the tail (the tip of the projection of $a$ on $b$), you get a right-angled triangle. By changing the definition of the scalar product, and repeating the drawing process, you could get a different triangle; e.g. acute or obtuse.

Maybe this is what the question is asking. Though I don't know how thew polynomials are involved.